# Tensor multiplication of Rank 3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have two tensors of rank 3 each, in other words two 3D matrix. I want to take dot product of these two matrix. I am confused to continue with this problem. Help me out with formula to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *3-way* tensor (or equivalently *3D* array or *3-order* array) need not necessarily be of rank-3; Here, "*rank of a tensor*" means the *minimum* number of rank-1 tensors (i.e. outer product of vectors; For *N*-way tensor, it's the outer product of *N* vectors) needed to get your original tensor. This is explained in the below figure of so-called **CP decomposition**.

[image: tensor-rank and CP decomposition]

In the above figure, the original tensor(***x***)  can be written as a sum of *R* rank-1 tensors, where *R* is a positive integer. In CP decomposition, we aim to find a minimum *R* that yields our original tensor ***X***. And this minimum *R* is called the rank of our original tensor.

For a 3-way tensor, it is the minimum number of (*a1,a2,a3...aR; b1,b2,b3...bR; c1,c2,c3...cR*) vectors (where each of the vectors is *n* dimensional) required to obtain the original tensor. The tensor can be written as the outer product of these vectors as:
[image: 3-way tensor]
[image: 3-way tensor explanation]

In terms of element-wise, we can write the 3-way tensor as:

[image: 3-way element-wise]

Now, with that background, to answer your specific question, to take the dot product (also called *tensor inner product*), both tensors must be of same shape (for e.g. 3x2x5 and 3x2x5), then the inner product is defined as the ***sum of the element-wise product of their values***.

[image: Tensor inner (or dot) product]

where the script ***X*** and ***Y*** are the same-shape tensors.

---

P.S.: The *tilde* in the above formulae should **not** be interpreted as an approximation.

Comment: @Hasnain I've added more details. Please have a look. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The vector inner product sum the elementwise products. The tensor inner product follows the same idea. Match the elements, multiply them, and add them all .